# how to find maximum and minimum values of a structure array

Tags: c++

I have a structure array of type float:

```
students[num].height
```

which contains 20 values from the program.
How can i write a function to find the maximum and minimum values of this structure array?

Answer (score 4):

Set a float variable max to the height member of the first element of the array, set a float variable min also to the first element's height memeber.  Loop over all the structures. As you are looping, if a height is greater than max, set max to that number. If a height is less than min, set min to that height.

Comment: im sorry, i dont really understand. so, float max = students[num].height    float min = students[num].height? how to loop over all the structures? i have never looped a structure before. please help.

Comment: Looping structure arrays. Also, how do i write the arguments?

Comment: Use a `for` loop and compare `students[i].height` to max and then min during each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

- Push back the elements to a std::vector
- Use [std::max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/) and [std::min_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/)

Comment: Assuming this is for a course, the OP may not have covered the standard library (or may not be allowed to use it).

Comment: @jonsca - OP should have mentioned it.

Comment: or don't push them into a std::vector.  The STL algorithms work just fine on C arrays.

Comment: @da code - You are correct. But how is it going to work in this case( elements are in each object of a structure )

Comment: overload < or provide a comparator

Answer (score 2):

```
   // student tStudentsArray[20] = ... 
   std::max_element(tStudentsArray, tStudentsArray + tNumberOfStudents,
        [] (const student& pLeft, const student& pRight) {
            return pLeft.height < pRight.height;
        });
```

..Any C++ class which does not cover the C++ standard library is kind of questionable.

Comment: I'm not talking about cout/cin/etc., but most professors (in my experience, at any rate) want the students to do the assignments the long way.  I've seen some that shun std::string completely.  I'm not saying it's right, I'm saying it's out there.

Comment: +1 for the use of the C pointers as iterators to max_element and the lambda comparator function

Comment: Any answer that uses language features that are not yet part of the language is also "kind of questionable", IMHO. You should at least state that you are using a feature not available in standard C++.

Comment: lambda functions are perfectly valid standard C++, just not widely supported.  But that's a compiler issue.

Comment: @jonsca Hm, then the situation has not changed much since I was a student. A while ago I was assistent professor myself and I have tried to go into advanced c++ programming in my classes but the students were simply not interested...

Comment: @Paul I'm not in teaching, but I help out on another site that has a higher percentage of students than are on here, and some of the limitations these professors place on students are astounding.  Things haven't changed very much, you are exactly right.

Comment: No I am not in teaching anymore either. What I see today are computer science graduates claiming they are "C++ experts" who almost faint after beeing confronted with a piece of boost (or boostified) code...

Answer (score 1):

Does the structure is being filled via your functions, or do you get it already filled?

If it it is being filled via your functions you can keep 2 variables max (initially set to MIN_INT) and min (initially set to MAX_INT).

For every insert check if the value is bigger than max or smaller than min, if so, set them to properly.

If it is not being filled via your function, I'd go with jonsca's answer.